# FFmpeg concat fade effect

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm currently using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i info.txt -s 1280x720 -crf 24 output.mp4
```

to join all videos in a folder. Before running the command I have entered "file " into the info.txt file. This works perfectly, but I would like to get a fade effect between all videos (crossfade). How is this possible? I have tried adding the following argument, but it didn't work. I found it online on an old post.

```
-filter_complex xfade=offset=4.5:duration=1
```

If anyone has a simple way of doing it, please let me know. I'm using the latest FFmpeg, so all features should be available.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?